# Function call doesn't work in IE8 (Object doesn't support this property or method)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, requirejs, slice, splice

I am calling a function with jQuery as below in a **RequireJS** application. I get an error stating that "**Object doesn't support this property or method**" on **IE8**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if($("body").hasClass("js-splash-overlay")){
        $("body").showSplashOverlay();
    }
});
```

**Splash overlay module.**

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery'], function($){

    return function(){

        $.fn.showSplashOverlay = function() {
            var $overlayData = $(this).find(".js-splash-data").html(),
                $overlayContent = $("<div id=\"overlayHolder\" class=\"js-overlay-holder\">" + $overlayData + "</div>"),
                $formElement =  $("form")[0],
                options = {
                     autoOpen: false,
                     closeOnEscape: false,
                     draggable: false,
                     autoResize:false,
                     hide: {
                         effect: "fade",
                         duration: 150
                     },
                     modal: true,
                     resizable: false,
                     show: {
                         effect: "fade",
                         duration: 150
                     },
                     width: 620,
                     maxWidth: 700,
                     minHeight:50,
                     fluid: true
                };

                $overlayContent.dialog(options).dialog("open");

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $formElement.submit();
                }, 1500);

            return this;
        };
    }
});
```

First, I thought jQuery might not be present at the time the call happens. However, when I `alert($("body").attr("class"))` it clearly shows the body `class`. Hence it's obvious that jQuery is present at the time of calling.

Above work absolutely fine with Chrome, FF and other latest browsers. Unfortunately, we do have to support **IE8** and requires the issue to be fixed.

**JQuery Version : 1.11**

**RequireJS Version : 2.1.11**

Many thanks and any advice or guidance is much appreciated. Happy to answer any questions.

**UPDATE: The issue was a rogue code that IE8 didn't like. It's called `splice`. Changing this to `slice` seems to make it work.**

Comment: Chances are very high that the issue is in `showSplashOverlay`, whatever that does ?

Comment: What line is actually throwing the error?

Comment: @adeneo Added spash overlay module to clear any doubt

Comment: @SeanVieira It's throwing the error exactly on the line where I call the showSplashOverlay()

Comment: So how is the code that is executing `showSplashOverlay` loaded?

Comment: @SeanVieira it's loaded in the RequireJS bootstrap file (the file that calls the eventHandlers). Above document.ready snippet is an extract from that file.

Comment: And is `splashOverlay` loaded as a dependency of the bootstrap file or any of its dependencies?

Comment: @SeanVieira spalshOverlay is loaded as a module from require.config with it's own dependencies (only jQuery) and called from the bootstrap file on document.ready.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58261/discussion-between-sean-vieira-and-chin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the answer was nothing to do with RequireJS. I had a `splice` command within my JS that somehow IE8 didn't like to work with. After changing the `splice` to **`slice`**.. it worked.

After much Googling around splice issue with early IE version, I have found that [this](http://www.to-string.com/2012/05/29/fixing-splice-in-older-versions-of-internet-explorer-8-and-olders/) issue is very common and has fixes from many people.

In my case, All I had to do was change

```
return Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0);
```

to

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE browsers with switched-off dev mode will throw an exception when you refer to **console** object

Comment: Sorry I only console.logged for Chrome. For IE8 I alerted the jQuery selector to see if jQuery is present. Changed the question to  reflect this.